# Pass a single JSON config variable to Terraform template using tfvars

Tags: terraform

I have this json file named:  dev.auto.tfvars.json, Its content:

```
{
  "config": {
    "KEY1": "VAL2",
    "KEY2": "VAL2"
  }
}
```

Now, I want to import the **config** (which is an object) into a single terraform environment variable in my terraform tf template, like this (main.tf file):

```
variable config { type = map }
...
resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      config = var.config
    }
  }
}
```

The purpose of this, is to read the whole JSON via 1 config variable in my app, server.js:

```
const allConfig = process.env.config;
console.log(allConfig.KEY1) // Will print VAL1
```

**I want to avoid** referencing each variable in my main.tf file like this (this is tedious):

```
variable KEY1{}
variable KEY2{}
...
resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      KEY1 = var.KEY1
      KEY2 = var.KEY2
    }
  }
```

When i am trying my solution above, terraform throws me an error:

```
var.config is a map of dynamic, known only after apply
Inappropriate value for attribute "variables": element "config": string
required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer in this stackoverflow post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63509997/3263659

Using `jsonencode` did the trick:

```
variable config { type = map }
...
resource "aws_lambda_function" "mylambda" {
  ...
  environment {
    variables = {
      config = jsonencode(var.config)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonencode instead of reading a json file. Check the [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) to get more examples.